# textbox not accepting digit 10

Tags: asp.net, html

I have validate a textbox to accept maxsize=2, it accepts 2 digit e.g 11,12... but it does not accepts digit 10

Here is my code

```
 <td width="60" height="20" class="case_txt" align="center">
    <input type="text" onblur="CheckUnitValue(this)" 
           name="Units_<%=cptData.Rows[k]["SERVICEID"] %>" 
           value="<%=cptData.Rows[k]["NOOFUNITS"] %>" 
           size="5" maxlength="2" onkeypress="onlyPositiveNumbers(this)" />
</td>
```

Comment: share your js functions

Comment: It looks like problem somewhere in  your `onlyPositiveNumbers` function. Input having type `text` and some maxlength doest't restricts any characters to be entered by itself.

Comment: thanks i fixed it with the following 

 function restrictLimit(el)
        {
            
            var max = 10;
            
            if(document.getElementsByName(el)[0].value > max || document.getElementsByName(el)[0].value == '0'){

                document.getElementsByName(el)[0].value = '';
            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a modern browser, you can use <`input type="number" min="1" max="99"`/> as Andy said.

For browsers that doesn't support `input type="number"` you can correct your script this way.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script>
        function validateRange(element) {
            value = +element.value;
            min = element.getAttribute('min');
            max = element.getAttribute('max');
            if (isNaN(value) || value < min || value > max) {
                element.value = '';
            }
            else
            {
                element.value = value;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="99" />
    <input type="text" maxlength="2" min="1" max="99" onblur="validateRange(this)" />
</body>
</html>
```

Note:

- It's better to use `onblure` instead on `onkeypress`, for example when the users pastes a text into field.
- I used 2 custom attrinutes `min` and `max` on `textbox` to keep `validateRange` function more reusable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're overcomplicating simple things.

If you need this textbox accepting only two-digit positive numbers, then you can use `type="number"` instead of `type="text"` and set limits for valid values.

Something like this:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="99"/>
```

Pretty simple, and you don't need any custom validation using javascript (I really suppose your `onlyPositiveNumbers` function has some mistakes as I've stated in comments).

Comment: i set the following as u mention , <input type="number" min="1" max="10"/>
but i can enter 11 ,12 ....etc

Comment: @RazimKhan if you've set `10` as max value - then yes, you technically can enter `11` in this field, but when you will move focus outside of this field (or submit form) - then this field will be marked as invalid (depends on browser, red rectangle around field and appropriate warning text in most cases). Also form will not be submitted if some fields are invalid.